# Custom configuration settings, custom ClientSettingsSection

Tags: c#, .net

Consider the following config section:

```
<configSections>
    <sectionGroup name="applicationSettings" type="System.Configuration.ApplicationSettingsGroup, System, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089">
        <section name="xxx.Properties.Settings" type="System.Configuration.ClientSettingsSection, System, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false"/>
    </sectionGroup>
</configSections>
<applicationSettings>
    <xxx.Properties.Settings>
        <setting name="xxx_Service1" serializeAs="String">
            <value>https://xxx.service1</value>
        </setting>
        <setting name="xxx_Service1" serializeAs="String">
            <value>https://xxx.service2</value>
        </setting>
        <setting name="xxx_Service1" serializeAs="String">
            <value>https://xxx.service3</value>
        </setting>
    </xxx.Properties.Settings>
</applicationSettings>
```

I try to implement custom version of **System.Configuration.ClientSettingsSection**. I need exactly same hierarchy

```
ConfigSection     
  -  ConfigElement      
  -  ConfigElement     
  -  ConfigElement
```

Base on code from `AssemblyExplorer` I wrote custom implementation:

```
{
    static void Main()
    {
        var sec = (CustomClientSettingsSection) ConfigurationManager.GetSection("serviceSettings");
        Console.Read();
    }
}

public class CustomClientSettingsSection : ConfigurationSection
{
    private static readonly ConfigurationProperty _propSettings = new ConfigurationProperty((string)null,
        typeof(CustomSettingElementCollection), (object)null, ConfigurationPropertyOptions.IsDefaultCollection);

    [ConfigurationProperty("", IsDefaultCollection = true)]
    public CustomSettingElementCollection Services
    {
        get { return (CustomSettingElementCollection)this[CustomClientSettingsSection._propSettings]; }
    }
}

public class CustomSettingElementCollection : ConfigurationElementCollection
{
    protected override ConfigurationElement CreateNewElement()
    {
        return new CustomSettingElement();
    }

    protected override object GetElementKey(ConfigurationElement element)
    {
        return ((CustomSettingElement)element).Key;
    }
}

public class CustomSettingElement : ConfigurationElement
{
    private static readonly ConfigurationProperty _propName = new ConfigurationProperty("name", typeof(string), (object)"", ConfigurationPropertyOptions.IsRequired | ConfigurationPropertyOptions.IsKey);

    internal string Key
    {
        get
        {
            return this.Name;
        }
    }

    [ConfigurationProperty("name", DefaultValue = "", IsKey = true, IsRequired = true)]
    public string Name
    {
        get
        {
            return (string)this[CustomSettingElement._propName];
        }
        set
        {
            this[CustomSettingElement._propName] = (object)value;
        }
    }
}
```

I am trying to parse this *config.xml*

```
  <configSections>
    <section name="serviceSettings" type="ConsoleApplication1.CustomClientSettingsSection, ConsoleApplication1"/>
  </configSections>
  <serviceSettings>
    <setting name="xxx_Service1">
    </setting>
    <setting name="xxx_Service2">
    </setting>
  </serviceSettings>
```

I get error:

> Unrecognized element 'setting'.

How to parse this config and get list of `configElement` with same attribute?

Comment: I would recommend to use XmlDocument and .GetElementsByTagName("setter")

Comment: i use custom config in configuration file , i have to read using ConfigurationManager

Comment: I'd suggest using the new configuration classes introduced with .NET Core instead. The packages are .NET Standard compliant which means they can be used by full framework projects as well. You wouldn't need *any* of that code to define sections and parse settings into objects.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is code I adapted from here to fit your example.

[Code Project: Custom Configuration Sections in app.config or web.config](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/233965/Custom-Configuration-Sections-in-app-config-or-web)

### I use Powershell and VS Code to test C# code

```
csc TestCodeApp.cs
.\TestCodeApp.exe
```

### TestCodeApp.exe.config

```
<configuration>
    <configSections>
        <section name="Services" type="TestCodeApp.ServicesConfig, TestCodeApp"/>
    </configSections>
    <Services>
        <setting name="xxx_Service1" value="this1"/>
        <setting name="xxx_Service2" value="this2"/>
    </Services>
</configuration>
```

### TestCodeApp.cs

```
using System;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace TestCodeApp {

    class TestCode {
        static void Main () {
            ExeConfigurationFileMap configMap = new ExeConfigurationFileMap { ExeConfigFilename = "TestCodeApp.exe.config" };
            Configuration config = ConfigurationManager.OpenMappedExeConfiguration (configMap, ConfigurationUserLevel.None);

            var section = (ServicesConfig) config.GetSection ("Services");

            // This fixes the below error
            // error CS0122: 'System.Configuration.ConfigurationElement.this[System.Configuration.ConfigurationProperty]' is inaccessible due to its protection level
            section.SectionInformation.UnprotectSection ();

            var services = section.Services;

            for (int i = 0; i < services.Count; i++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(services[i].Name + " - " + services[i].Value);
            }            
        }
    }

    public class ServicesConfig : ConfigurationSection {
        [ConfigurationProperty("", IsRequired = true, IsDefaultCollection = true)]
        [ConfigurationCollection(typeof(ServicesCollection), AddItemName = "setting")]
        public ServicesCollection Services {
            get { return ((ServicesCollection) (this[""])); }
        }
    }

    [ConfigurationCollection (typeof (ServicesElement))]
    public class ServicesCollection : ConfigurationElementCollection {
        protected override ConfigurationElement CreateNewElement () {
            return new ServicesElement ();
        }

        protected override object GetElementKey (ConfigurationElement element) {
            return ((ServicesElement) (element)).Name;
        }

        public ServicesElement this [int index] {
            get {
                return (ServicesElement) BaseGet (index);
            }
        }
    }

    public class ServicesElement : ConfigurationElement {
        [ConfigurationProperty ("name", DefaultValue = "",
            IsKey = true, IsRequired = true)]
        public string Name {
            get {
                return ((string) (base["name"]));
            }
            set {
                base["name"] = value;
            }
        }

        [ConfigurationProperty ("value", DefaultValue = "",
            IsKey = false, IsRequired = false)]
        public string Value {
            get {
                return ((string) (base["value"]));
            }
            set {
                base["value"] = value;
            }
        }      
    }
}
```

I tested it and it works nicely. Let me know if you have questions.

Comment: thanks for you answer and time . you gave a standard example . it work fine, but the problem is different. In your file: Section->ElementCollection ->Elements , in my file: Section->Elements.  there is no CustomSettingElementCollection  between Section and Element nodes. Right after <xxx.Properties.Settings> go <setting <setting  <setting  elements arrow

Comment: Ok. I take back my words. It can be done. I just had a eureka moment. I edited the answer.

Comment: The key is to use IsDefaultCollection=true and this[""] to be able to access the collection within the section itself and not under another node.